# Is the "Async" suffix required in the name of an async ASP.NET MVC 4 action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

Given the following ASP.NET MVC 4 controller action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> FooAsync()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");
        string response = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return Content(response);
    }
}
```

Do I need to put the "Async" suffix in *FooAsync* for the action to be run asynchronously?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951774/does-the-use-of-the-async-suffix-in-a-method-name-depend-on-whether-the-async

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, this is not a requirement.

> By convention, you append "Async" to the names of methods that have 
>       an Async or async modifier.
>
> You can ignore the convention where an event, base class, or interface 
>       contract suggests a different name. For example, you shouldn’t rename 
>       common event handlers, such as Button1_Click.

source: [MSDN: Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await C# -> Naming Convetions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#)

Comment: According to [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4), "Appending 'Async' is not required but is the convention when writing asynchronous methods."

Comment: @StephenCleary - Thank you for confirming that. The link I provided also points to Naming Conventions. However, not including the word "Async" as a suffix will have no affect on the method, and so it is not necessarily "Required".

Comment: @TravisJ: Thanks, Travis, I know about the convention; however, I wanted to know if the suffix was actually *required*.

Comment: @MariusSchulz - I clearly stated "**No, it is not a requirement**". You *do not* have to append the suffix *Async* to the methods.

Comment: @TravisJ: Yes, but the source you provided is talking about conventions, which I know about. Anyway, since your answer is correct, I've accepted it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 18):

Although it's not a requirement, I like to follow convention and see the "...Async" suffix on my asynchronous methods, so I tend to use the `ActionName` attribute to decorate the controller actions with the non-async name, this way you can have your cake and eat it too :)

```
[ActionName("Index")]
public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
    return View();
}
```

I find this works just fine.