# How to call web method in C# asynchronously?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

How to call web method in c# using async. I'm using like below

```
    public void SaveSuggestedItems(string emailbody, string OrderHeaderID)
    {
       try{
            ...
        }
        catch{
           ...
        }
    }
```

and in c# Im using like this

```
  public async Task<string> saveSuggestedItem()
    {
        OHDWebService OHDService = new OHDWebService();
        var saveSuggestedItem = OHDService.SaveSuggestedItems(eBody.Text, hfdOrderRecordID.Value);
        var suggestedItems = await saveSuggestedItem;
        return suggestedItems;
    }
```

but it is showing error like cannot assign void to an implicit typed local variable

Comment: You can't try to assing the return value fo a void method like `SaveSuggestedItems` to a variable. This has nothing to do with async/await. `async/await` won't make anything asynchronous automagically either, they make *awaiting* already asynchronous operations easier. Whatever is inside `SaveSuggestedItems` should use asynchronous methods itself

Comment: BTW that's explained in ASP.NET tutorials. You'll probably save a lot of time if you follow a tutorial before starting a new project. Check for example [Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 4):

You need to make the method async. Change this:

```
public void SaveSuggestedItems(string emailbody, string OrderHeaderID)
```

to this:

```
public async Task SaveSuggestedItems(string emailbody, string OrderHeaderID)
```

Now you can await it.

Note: You don't have to (and can't) actually `return` the Task explicitly. The compiler generates one for you.

Also, consider [changing the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652773/is-the-async-suffix-required-in-the-name-of-an-async-asp-net-mvc-4-action) to `SaveSuggestedItemsAsync()`.

Finally, make sure there's [actually a need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498942/why-shouldnt-all-functions-be-async-by-default) to make it async.

Comment: Thanq, actually "SaveSuggestedItems" method is reside in webservice its return type is void so we cant assign void to local variable, but i want to call that method in C# using asyn, so i created that function  "saveSuggestedItem", I want make saveSuggestedItem as async but its giving error.

Comment: Is `SaveSuggestedItems` code that was generated by adding a service reference? You need to tell Visual Studio to [generate async or task-based methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777710/how-to-use-visual-studio-generated-async-wcf-calls) as well (in the dialog that is shown when adding the reference).

Answer (score 2):

Just replace:

```
var saveSuggestedItem = OHDService.SaveSuggestedItems(eBody.Text, hfdOrderRecordID.Value);
```

to standard calling:

```
OHDService.SaveSuggestedItems(eBody.Text, hfdOrderRecordID.Value);
```

Your problem appears because you try to assign `void` to some variable and your method does not return any type. It's not related to async calling.